# Do preprocessors expand macros surrounded by quotation marks?

Tags: c, unix, fortran, preprocessor

Do common preprocessors like cpp and fpp expand macros surrounded by a pair of quotation marks?

I tried the following code using both cpp and fpp, it seems that the macros within quotation marks are not expanded. However, I did not find this rule in any documentation about cpp or fpp. Could anyone kindly direct me to some documentation so that I can be sure about this behavior? Thanks.

```
#define X Y
X
"X"
'X'
```

Comment: If you want to use one param a literal string you should use `#` for example`#X`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do common preprocessors like cpp and fpp expand macros surrounded by a
> pair of quotation marks?

The C language specification describes the behavior of conforming C preprocessors.  The actual standards for C are not freely available, but you can get copies of late drafts.  For C18, for example, you could refer to [N2176](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).  In particular, you should have a look at sections 5.1.1.2 and 6.10.3.  Of particular relevance is footnote 173 in section 6.10.3:

> Since, by macro-replacement time, all character constants and string
> literals are preprocessing tokens, not sequences possibly containing
> identifier-like subsequences (see 5.1.1.2, translation phases), they
> are never scanned for macro names or parameters.

(Substantially the same text appears in earlier versions of the standard, too.)

The bottom line for C, then, is that **no**, a conforming C preprocessor does not perform macro replacement on the contents of string literals or character constants.

---

The situation for Fortran is less clear cut, because the Fortran language specification does not define preprocessing facilities.  There is an `include` statement built in to the language itself, but Fortran practitioners generally would not consider its use to involve preprocessing.  Fortran source code rarely relies on preprocessing features such as macro expansion or conditional compilation.

Some Fortran implementations nevertheless do provide a preprocessing facility, sometimes available as a standalone program named `fpp`.  You would need to consult the documentation of your specific `fpp` for details, but generally these are adaptations of the C preprocessor to Fortran syntax.  As such, **no**, I would not expect a Fortran preprocessor to perform macro expansion on the contents of character literals.  I am not aware of any implementations that defy my expectations in that regard.

Comment: Once upon a time Fortran did specify a preprocessor (but not now).

Comment: I've been around Fortran for quite a long time, @francescalus, and to the best of my knowledge, none of Fortran 66, Fortran 77, Fortran 90, Fortran 95, Fortran 2003, Fortran 2008, or Fortran 2018 define a preprocessor.  Am I overlooking something, or did you mean something different from all of those when you said "Fortran"?

Comment: ISO/IEC 1539-3:1999.

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus, that had flown beneath my radar.  After a bit of research, however, I find that it appears the optional Fortran 95 preprocessor specified by ISO/IEC 1539-3:1999 supported only conditional compilation, not macro replacement.  Thus, although its existence is an interesting historical note, that preprocessor is not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Oh yes, it affects your answer not the slightest. Not even "the Fortran language specification does not define preprocessing facilities" because Fortran no longer does.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and references!

Answer (score 3):

For C (don't know Fortran but might be the same):

> Do processors expand macros surrounded by quotation marks?

No.

A macro won't get expanded when the identifier of the macro is part of a *string literal* (`""`) or *character constant* (`''`). Then the macro identifier/name becomes part of the string literal/character constant.

`"X"` - This is a *string literal* of the characters `'X'` + `'\0'`.

`'X'` - This is a *character constant* for the letter `X`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Another point of view is: preprocessor substitutes tokens/identifiers, and it is useful for that. A literal (either numerical or string) is not an identifier, and it would be useless - and, much risky - to substitute it.

Another answer mentions that the C conformant preprocessor is supposed to not substitute literal strings. To go one step beyond, I tried to compile the following program:

```
#define 12 13
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  printf("%i\n", 12);
}
```

and the result (gcc version 8.3.0, Debian 8.3.0-6) is:

```
test.c:1:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
 #define 12 13
         ^~
```

I think this demonstrates that the preprocessor wants to work with identifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and explanations!